# How exactly infix notation in custom extractors work?

Tags: scala

In the example below, I have a ** object with apply and unapply methods. I am trying to understand how exactly the infix notation in the 2nd case works. I could not find anything that explains how the infix notation is de-sugared.

```
object ** {
  def apply[A, B](a: A, b: B) = (a, b)
  def unapply[A, B](p: (A, B)) = Some(p)

}

object CheckExtractor extends App {

  val v = **(1, "a")

  v match {
    case **(x, y) => println(s"extractor pattern 1: values $x and $y")
  }
  // extractor pattern 1: values 1 and a

  (v, 2) match {
    case x ** y ** z => println(s"extractor pattern 2: values $x and $y and $z")
  }
  // extractor pattern 2: values 1 and a and 2
}
```

For 2nd case statement, unapply is actually performed on `((1,"a"),2)` which in turn returns `Some((1,"a"),2)`. And I do not quite get how it is structurally equivalent to `x ** y ** z`, unless it translates to `apply(apply(x,y),z) == ((x,y),z)`. but this is clearly not the case because the pattern works even if we take out the apply method

Comment: `a Foo b` is desugared as `Foo(a, b)` , and depending on the name of the operator it will associate by the left or by the right.

Comment: thank you! in this case the unapply is actually performed on ((1,"a"),2) which in turn returns Some((1,"a"),2). And I do not quite get how it is structurally equivalent to x ** y ** z, unless it translates to apply(apply(x,y),z) == ((x,y),z). but this is clearly not the case because the pattern works even if i take out the apply method

Comment: Because it is not calling `apply` but `unapply` because its pattern matching, so the pattern `x ** y ** z` is equivalent to calling `**.unapply((**.unapply(v), 2))`  which will then return `((1, "a"), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `x ** y ** z` expects to get `Some((Some((A, B)), C))`. It uses `unapply` of `**` on the received value to match it. As it's nested, we have a call `**.unapply((**.unapply(v), 2))` which returns `Some((Some((1, "a")), 2))`, which matches `Some((Some((A, B)), C))`.